# Load pictures from SD card and show it in a imageview

Tags: android, image, cursor

I' trying to load all the pictures from the sdcard and show it in a imageview of my android application. I have one cursor for read the pictures and put it into an arraylist of bitmap. Now I can load all the pictures of the sdcard but when I print it into a imageview it isn't showing. Please help me if someone know how to do it.

Thank you.
This is the code of the activity.

```
public class VerFotos extends Activity{
public static ArrayList<Bitmap> imagenes;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    imagenes=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    String[] imgColumnID = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor=managedQuery(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imgColumnID,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
    new String[] { "%sdcard/%" }, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        String result=cursor.getString(0);
        byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(result,Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
        imagenes.add(bitmap);
    }
    String imag=getIntent().getStringExtra("position");
    int index=Integer.parseInt(imag);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_ver_fotos);
    ExtendedViewPager mViewPager=(ExtendedViewPager)findViewById(R.id.image);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new TouchImageAdapter());
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(index);
}
static class TouchImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imagenes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        TouchImageView img=new TouchImageView(container.getContext());
        img.setImageBitmap(imagenes.get(position));
        container.addView(img, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        return img;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view==object;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating through the results in a loop, you're only getting the first result. Try this:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String result=cursor.getString(0);
    byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(result,Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
    imagenes.add(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: I will add a loop. But if I get only the first result I'll get one picture but I don't get anything and array's size is 1.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? If you aren't getting any results, how is the ArrayList's size 1?

Comment: I think it put into the array a null value and it's 1 for this. I try with the loop and I get the following error: `Failed to read row 1, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 6 rows, 1 columns`

Comment: Sorry I'd made a mistake, try the edited version above.

Comment: I have all the pictures but it isn't show in the imageview. I know I get all because the size is 6 now.

Comment: Can you revise your question, it doesn't mention that the images aren't showing.

Comment: I've edit the post. I have all the pictures but the imageview is empty